# Plotting points in matPlotLib results in weird axes ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, evolutionary-algorithm

I am reading these lines

```
1 6734 1453
2 2233 10
3 5530 1424
4 401 841
```

with this code

```
for line in tspSpec:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    coordList.append(line.split(' '))

# grab coordinates from list
xCoords = [line[1] for line in coordList]
yCoords = [line[2] for line in coordList]

plt.plot(xCoords, yCoords, '.')
plt.show()
```

the name of the file I'm reading from is tspSpec, hence the 'for line in tspSpec'. I want to visualize what these points will look like on a plot, but when I use matPlotLib to plot them, the axes range is not increasing vertically up and horizontally right as it should. Instead, the points are plotted in the order they are 'received'. Is this the intended behavior of matPlotLib? If not, could someone better explain it to me and suggest a fix for my code? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You need to convert the strings to numeric: `xCoords = [float(line[1]) for line in coordList]`

Comment: @JohanC Worked perfect. Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple.